# Trying to understand the relationship between these CSS transforms

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS transforms and I am trying to understand the relationship between them so I can figure out how to compensate for one of them.

Here is my code:

```css
.background {
  height: 720px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1280px;
  background-color: rgb(205, 163, 163);
}
.text {
  transform: matrix(0, 1, -1, 0, 700, 206.66071428571);
  width: 306px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px;
  font-size: 120px;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
.top-left {
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.center-center {
  transform-origin: center center 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="top-left text">
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center-center text">
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
transforms-origin: center center;
```

and

```css
transform-origin: top left;
```

Are the CSS properties in question.

You will see two pieces of text, both with the same properties, except for their transform-origin.

I am trying to understand why the text with the "center center" origin is being placed where it is. I would assume the central point of its "bounding box" would be at the same spot of the top left corner of the bounding box of the other piece of text?

I am looking to figure out the relationship between the two so I can potentially shift the text with the "center center" origin to be in place of the other text.

Comment: As a side note, the browser support for `transform-origin` is iffy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: its lets you modify the origin for transformations of an element. have a look here for more info. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: I understand what the property does, I want to understand the relationship between these two pieces of text as the one with center center should be closer to the other, as its center point is no where near the top left coords it has.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to understand, I have changed your matrix for an aproximate composite transform. You have a translate and a rotate 90 deg. And I have reduced the translate amount so that it fits more easily in the snippet. But the math remains unchanged.

Now notice that the center of transforms (wait for the animation to take place) are not where you might expect, the divs are not in the same place than the ps. I have added a border to the div so that it is easier to see.

About the translation involved, you are rotating around the center of the div. or around the top left corner. The distance between those points is half the width of the div, and half the height:

153px 60px

Now, when you rotate that 90deg, the equivalent translation is the sum and the rest of those values:

213px 93px

Hover on the snippet to see those values applied, and the 2 ps aligned

```css
.background {
  height: 99%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(205, 163, 163);
}
.text {
  transform: translate(300px, 100px) rotate(90deg);
  width: 306px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 120px;
  font-size: 120px;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border: solid 1px black;
  animation: show 4s infinite;
  
}
.top-left {
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.center-center {
  transform-origin: center center 0px;
}

@keyframes show {
    0% {  transform: translate(300px, 100px) rotate(90deg);}
    5% {  transform: translate(300px, 100px) rotate(90deg);}
  100% {  transform: translate(300px, 100px) rotate(0deg);}
}

body:hover .text {
  animation: none;
  }

body:hover .center-center p {
    transform: translate(93px, 213px);  
}

p {transition: 1s; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="top-left text">
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
  <div class="center-center text">
    <p>TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

To understand that in the general case. Changing the transform origin is equivalent, in a mathematical sense, to do a translate (from one origin to the other), apply the transform, and do the inverse of the translate.

This translate, since you are moving from center center to top left, is half the width, half the height.

when you apply to this value the matrix, the uniform terms are negligible, and you end with x2 = x1 * a00 + y1 * a01   and y2 = x1 * a10 + y1 * a11.

The final movement is that last calculus minus the first translate. Just check that my original answer is the special case for the matrix provided in your question

Comment: The problem is that if the text is rotated to a different angle, the translation to put it in the correct place isn't going to be the same as for my example. I'll do a second codepen tomorrow to show you.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpLVXx Take alook at this fork of the codepen. I have rotated the text to 45 degrees. You'll see that to get the text with origin "center center" you cannot apply the same translation (shifting the top left coords) to make it fit where the text with origin "top left" sits. This is the issue. Why does origin "center center" not sit where the coords tell it to sit?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbGeVJ Here you translation works. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpLVEv here it does not. I have done the exact same translation, but the 45 degree boxes do not overlap. To get them close, I used the coords 480, 300, but I can't find the correlation between those coords and the original coords. It doesn't match up.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGLzLb Another example. This time rotated 270 degrees. This shows you again that your original translation works, but only for cases where the object is not "slanted". NB - the "bounding box" for the 45 degree rotated boxes is approx 302px square, but despite knowing this, I cannot get the correct translation. Basically, I need one rule to suite all degrees of rotation.

Comment: I see you edited your post. Are you able to figure out the translation when the text is rotated 45 degrees? Also, what are a00, a01, a10 and a11?

Answer (score -1):

The transform-origin property allows you to change the position of transformed elements.

2D transformations can change the x- and y-axis of an element. 3D transformations can also change the z-axis of an element.

to better understnad. Here is the live demo from **W3schools.com** :http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trycss3_transform-origin_inuse.htm

Example CSS with browser prefixes.

**CSS**

```
div {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transform-origin: 20% 40%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 20% 40%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 20% 40%;
}
```

Comment: A lot of people don't like w3schools but I would recommend them to newbies and even some novice programmers since their ui and ux is nicer than w3cs. Another great thing is the live examples. Also check out Chris from css-tricks.com and David Walsh from http://davidwalsh.name

Comment: David and Chris are very great people to learn from if ever needed. Chris is more to a CSS guy though he does have other tuts. David Walsh though is inspiring in most of what he puts out.!

Comment: Its not that I want to know what transform origin does, I know what it does. What I can't figure out is why the text with center center origin is in the position it is, as its center point is not at the coordinates of its top and left properties.